# How to delete old data?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have a lot of old data. And I want to delete it.

**Data example:**

*id ,title, date*

What is the best way to delete old data using SQL? I mean delete row if too old, for example  1 month. How can I compare row's date with current time?

PS. I have date column. Look at the example.

Comment: If your row does not contain any date information there is no way to delete it.

Comment: Look at the example. I have date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sommething like this:-

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE [columndate]< DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. Happy coding!!! P.S. Dont forget to accept it as answer with an upvote!!! :)

Comment: Yes. I'm waiting for few minutes.

Comment: I know that...I was asking for the coward downvoter who has not even thought to put a comment for it ;) Anyways happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't any row which stores when was the data inserted then it cannot be specified.
If there is a row named `createddate`,

you can try

```
delete from mytable where DATEDIFF(createddate, now())>30
```

OR you can try with

```
delete from mytable where createddate< DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: >30. What is that? Seconds, days?

Comment: How can I set seconds or another step in 1st query?

Comment: You can use the TIMEDIFF method for seconds

Answer (score -1):

DELETE * FROM TableName WHERE date < DATE();